# API Spotify show artists

Tags: python, api, spotify

So im trying to become better in working with API's.

I found an exercise where i have to search for an artist and the api replies with all the artists related to that name.

I have read the docs on spotify developer but i can't fix my code.

I always get the same error that my API link is not working.

Can anyone maybe fix my code and explain what needed to be done.
Do not forget to change the CLIENT ID and SECRET.

[image: End result]

```py
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
CLIENT_ID = "your client id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "your client secret"

auth_response = requests.post(main_api, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET,
})

auth_response_data = auth_response.json()

access_token = auth_response_data['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'.format(token=access_token)
}

print(access_token)

BASE_URL = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/'

artist_name = input("Give artist name: ")

r = requests.get(BASE_URL + 'search/' + artist_name + '/artists', headers=headers, params={'include_groups': 'artists', 'limit':50})

print("URL: " + str(r))

d = r.json()

print(BASE_URL + 'search/' + artist_name + "/artists")


print("Name")

for artists in d['items']:
    print(artists['name'], ' --- ', artists['genres'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You've been sending the request to a wrong endpoint (sort of) and with an invalid payload. According to the [docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/) this is what a sample request should look like:

> curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=tania%20bowra&type=artist" -H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"

And here's how you would do it in Python:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests

main_api = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
auth_response = requests.post(main_api, {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'client_id': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret': "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET",
})

access_token = auth_response.json()['access_token']
headers = dict(Authorization=f"Bearer {access_token}")

API_URL = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/"
query = {
    "q": "justinbieber",
    "type": "artist",
    "limit": "5",
}
end_point = "search?"
api_response = requests.get(f"{API_URL}{end_point}{urlencode(query)}", headers=headers).json()

for artists in api_response["artists"]["items"]:
    print(f"{artists['name']} --- {artists['genres']}")
```

Output:

```
Justin Bieber  ---  ['canadian pop', 'dance pop', 'pop', 'post-teen pop']
Justin Timberlake  ---  ['dance pop', 'pop']
Justin Drew Bieber  ---  []
Justin Bieber Tribute Team  ---  ['fake']
Justin Bieber's Karaoke Band  ---  []
```